# meaning of fruit fly in a sentence

Tags: american-english, technology

What is the meaning of the word fruit fly in the context of a business/technology conversation?

Example: This technology is a fruit fly which is good and bad!

Comment: I think it has to do with certain flies' short life span. In Danish we use the idiom "... it is a one-day fly" (one-day fly is a direct translation, the actual insect is a mayfly), for something that is judged to last very shortly.

Comment: English has the same idiom. I haven't seen "fruit fly" used for that though. It's possible that the originator of the communication wasn't familiar with mayflies.

Comment: @user888379 - Mayhaps you are right.

Comment: *Fruit flies* are short-lived critters, true, but in either language, that’s rather vague.

*Fruit flies* are a favourite in genetics labs not because of their short *lives* but specifically because of their short *breeding cycle*.

Stefan’s *one-day fly* is a perfect description of any kind of *ephemera* but do *fruit flies* don’t belong there?

Under all that, does anyone think *which is good and bad* could make any difference? How would dropping it change the original, or any speculative meaning?